# Take an app into foreground without launching it

Tags: android, notifications, background-service, foreground-service

I am new to android. All i need is `when my device gets connected to Bluetooth, a specific app should start in foreground, but should not get launched, user will only be able to see the app in the`notification`.

I looked up in web but don't find any satisfactory answer. My requirement is, app should get launched, but user should not feel it, he/she will able to see the app notification along with `quit` button in notification bar.

I want to know about the possibility in android as well as iOS

Comment: you can use service for this

Comment: as said above, combine service with broadcast receiver to detect bluetooth connection

Comment: register a broadcast receiver for bluetooth. and in the listener create an app notification

Answer (score 1):

Add broadcast receiver in your activity with the application context.

```
registerReceiver(getApplicationContext(), new IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED));

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            public void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();

                if (BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED.equals(action)) {
                    if(intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, -1) 
    == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON)
    // Bluetooth is connected, add notification here
}

}

        };
```

Also add this in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

You can find the example for notifications [HERE](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-notification)